# What is the discrete equivalent to the 4-plot?

Tags: discrete-data, exploratory-data-analysis

Quoting [NIST](http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/eda/section2/eda21.htm), when analyzing a continuous variable, one needs to validate four assumptions that typically underlie all measurement processes; namely, that the data at hand "behave like":

- random drawings;
- from a fixed distribution;
- with the distribution having fixed location; and
- with the distribution having fixed variation.

The [4-plot](http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/eda/section3/4plot.htm) is a great way to validate these assumptions.

My questions are the following:

- What are equivalent assumptions for a discrete variable?
- What would be the best set of graphics to validate them?